# How can I make nrepl-ritz-jack-in work remotely over TRAMP / Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

### What I want:

I have a clojure program on a remote site, let's call it `mccarthy`.
What I want to do is connect to a `nrepl-ritz` from my laptop, preferably using `nrepl-ritz-jack-in`.  The jack in works fine for a local program, but doesn't seem to connect to a remote program.

### Attempt 1

<kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> on `/mccarthy:code/program/project.clj`

`(require 'nrepl-ritz)`

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl-ritz-jack-in`

### Result

Emacs appears to hang.  If I go to the `*nrepl-server*` buffer, I see this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.invoke(Main.java:117)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.start(Main.java:88)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: project
    at leiningen.ritz_nrepl$start_jpda_server.invoke(ritz_nrepl.clj:23)
    at leiningen.ritz_nrepl$ritz_nrepl.doInvoke(ritz_nrepl.clj:95)
```

(and tons of other lines, too...)

I am using `drip` on my laptop, but not on `mccarthy`, so clearly `nrepl-ritz-jack-in` is not detecting that it's a remote file.  Regular old `nrepl-jack-in` will work as expected in this case, however.

### Attempt 2

I also tried starting an `nrepl-ritz` using `lein` on `mccarthy`:

```
mattox@mccarthy$ lein ritz-nrepl
nREPL server started on port 42874
```

From my laptop I forward a port so local `42874` connects to `42874` on `mccarthy`:

```
ssh -L 42874:localhost:42874 -N mccarthy
```

Then, from my local Emacs:

```
(require 'nrepl-ritz)
```

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl`

Host: `127.0.0.1`

Port: `42874`

This gives me a connection:

```
; nREPL 0.1.7-preview
user>
```

So to test it out, I run

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl-ritz-threads`

It gives me a nice table of threads.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl-ritz-break-on-exception`

```
user> (/ 1 0)
```

### Result

This hangs, but sometimes shows a hidden debugging buffer with some restarts available.  If I tell it to pass the exception back to the program, it never gives control back to the REPL.

I've done plenty of searches but have not been able to get anything more specific than "make sure lein is on your path" (And I did do that, on both machines...).

Comment: `(/ 1 0)` - this hangs? Probably trying to evaluate infinity... ;-)

Comment: Trying the `Attempt 2` in your local machine, it does work ok? That is starting `lein ritz-repl` and then connecting from emacs

Comment: Yes, starting from my local machine worked fine.  It's just remote connections that have trouble.

Comment: If you follow these steps it should work: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/debugging-clojure

Comment: Already answered bro. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908315/clojure-connection-issue-re-running-cider-jack-in It's not exactly what your looking for but it'll help

Comment: As lame as it might sound, it seams that a restart for both machines is in order. Are you sure you do not have other instances of the same software lurking in the background and therefore making trouble?

Comment: Judging by the number of upvotes, it is probably a it more involved than a restart.

Comment: you can try this link http://ianeslick.com/2013/05/17/clojure-debugging-13-emacs-nrepl-and-ritz/. it may help.

Comment: You just hit a jackpot in SO with this questions, 1 from me as well. Although all of these technologies are new to me.

Comment: In the unlikely event that this is a bug...stay calm and [report it]

Comment: you can try [drawbackz](http://buzz.drawbackz.com/2014/12/how-can-i-make-nrepl-ritz-jack-in-work.html)

Answer (score 1):

> If the repl is still running from the previous cider-jack-in, you should either use the cidercommand to connect to the running instance, or stop the previous before starting a new one

From Here `[Clojure - connection issue re-running cider-jack-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908315/clojure-connection-issue-re-running-cider-jack-in)

Also see this `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/debugging-clojure`